# How can i understand advance jquery concepts

Tags: javascript, jquery

Every now and then whenever i see any code for plugin, i could not understand the 80% of code.
I know some jquery as well and have been successful with it but i could not find those ways of doing things which they have done in plugins.

usually the code which i do in 10 lines , they do some shortcuts and finish in 1 one with advanced methods.

eg this is the code from jquery fileupload plugin

```
 // Callback for uploads start, equivalent to the global ajaxStart event:
            start: function (e) {
                var that = $(this).data('fileupload');
                that._transition($(this).find('.fileupload-progress')).done(
                    function () {
                        that._trigger('started', e);
                    }
                );
            },
```

I have no idea what the heck is going on , why the function name starts with underscore. what done is doing and all that.

Where i can find that sort of stuff fully explained with examples so that i can also reduce my code

Comment: Every plugin has it's own methods. Except that you must be familiar with javascript and jQuery methods as well, try to find the plugin's documentation. For the file upload, have a look at https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I understand it:

`start` is callback function, as comment says `Callback for uploads start, equivalent to the global ajaxStart event`

`var that` is eq. to:

[Returns value at named data store for the element, as set by jQuery.data(element, name, value), or the full data store for the element.](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/)

When variable `that` is set, there is a call for function named `_transition` which I guess is some extension of Ajax call as we later on call `done` function. Probably author owns work, so you'll need to search through code.

This function gets as a parameter object list returned by [`$(this).find('.fileupload-progress')`](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) selector.

At last, we call `done` function which I guess is eq. to [jQuery.ajax().done()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), called after sucessfull Ajax request. Inside done there is another callback for annonymous function

```
.done(function(){
    ....
})
```

Where there's fired another function called `_trigger` with string `started` and callback event of main function start `e`.

**And answer for your last question:**

`Where i can find that sort of stuff fully explained with examples so that i can also reduce my code?`

The truth is that without writting own stuff, you'll probably never learn that. Experience and coding is the key here. By searching for certain solutions, you'll find out new stuff like this one for example. So keep coding mate!